# DB Architecture Design - One foreign key referencing 2 primary keys in separate tables

Tags: sql, foreign-key-relationship, primary-key-design

I have a data architecture design question I'm hoping you can help me with. I cannot change the current architecture of the design, I can only add to it.

**Current set up**

- I have 2 tables `customerType1` & `customerType2` - both contain a `customerId` column and a surrogate `ID` filed which is an incrementing identity field
- When these customers are billed, the bills are recorded for both `customerType1` & `customerType2`, in the same table.

**Problem**

- I want to link this billing table to the `customerType` tables without having to have 2 foreign keys listed in `Billing` table, one for each surrogate ID.

Can anyone advise on how best to deal with this?

thanks in advance,

regards,

Dave

Comment: A foreign key will **only** ever reference **exactly one** table - there's no way around this, this is the way to do it properly. So in your case, you'll have **two foreign key columns** - one referencing `customerType1`, the other `customerType2`. In this case, you can enable actual referential integrity at the database level, which is the whole point of having foreign keys in the first place. Any other solution (like one "pseudo-FK" column and a second "customer type" column or something) is a sad hack and not worth implementing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying marc_s. I assume that these will have to be nullable foreign key constraints as only one can ever be populated?

Comment: Yes, those need to be nullable, since one of the two will ever have a value.